# JS: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, typeerror, visual-editor, getcomputedstyle

In short: I am trying to understand the meaning of this TypeError:
Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'
The error appears while lunching Mediawiki's VisualEditor, as can be seen here:

http://www.wiki.org.il/index.php?title=new-page&veaction=edit

The error doesn't enables creating new pages or editing the wiki anonymously. 
However, with the use of a different skin the error disappears:

http://www.wiki.org.il/index.php/Main_Page?useskin=vector

The wiki runs on 1.25alpha.

Answer (score 22):

I had this same error showing. When I replaced jQuery selector with normal JavaScript, the error was fixed.

```
var this_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

Replace:

```
getComputedStyle( $('#'+this_id)[0], "")
```

With:

```
getComputedStyle( document.getElementById(this_id), "")
```

Comment: getComputedStyle( document.getElementById(this_id)) will not work. getting the same error

Comment: It could be that at the time your `getComputedStyle(...)` code runs the element with id `this_id` is not actually present in the DOM. If your also dealing with adding/removing elements that is.

Comment: In my case I was initializing a `.collapsible` Element, but my structure was wrong, I had a `form` container for each `li` Element. Removing the `form` solved it.

Answer (score 7):

The error message says that `getComputedStyle` requires the parameter to be `Element` type. You receive it because the parameter has an incorrect type.

The most common case is that you try to pass an element that doesn't exist as an argument:

```
my_element = document.querySelector(#non_existing_id);
```

Now that element is `null`, this will result in mentioned error:

```
my_style = window.getComputedStyle(my_element);
```

If it's not possible to always get element correctly, you can, for example, use the following to end function if `querySelector` didn't find any match:

```
if (my_element === null) return;
```

Answer (score 4):

#### For those who got this error in AngularJS and not jQuery:

I got it in AngularJS v1.5.8 by trying to `ng-include` a `type="text/ng-template"` that didn't exist.

```
 <div ng-include="tab.content">...</div>
```

Make sure that when you use ng-include, the data for that directive points to an actual page/section. Otherwise, you probably wanted:

```
<div>{{tab.content}}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was using `ClassName`.

```
getComputedStyle( document.getElementsByClassName(this_id)) //error
```

It will also work without 2nd argument `" "`.

Here is my complete running code :

```
function changeFontSize(target) {

  var minmax = document.getElementById("minmax");

  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle
        ? getComputedStyle(minmax) // Standards
        : minmax.currentStyle;     // Old IE

  var fontSize;

  if (computedStyle) { // This will be true on nearly all browsers
      fontSize = parseFloat(computedStyle && computedStyle.fontSize);

      if (target == "sizePlus") {
        if(fontSize<20){
        fontSize += 5;
        }

      } else if (target == "sizeMinus") {
        if(fontSize>15){
        fontSize -= 5;
        }
      }
      minmax.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  }
}


onclick= "changeFontSize(this.id)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced the same issue in a jQuery plugin that I'm modifying for my own use. Basically, you can see from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) that the parameter passed into `getComputedStyle` must be of type `Element`. Your plugin is passing `window`, the global variable pointing to the browser window, which is of type `Window` (who would have guessed?) into the function call. Their code looks something like this, I'm guessing:

```
var x = window.getComputedStyle(e);
```

They're probably calling this from a generic function that didn't verify that `e` is actually an `Element` and not a `Window`.

In my case, I'm only trying to circumvent the jQuery `width()` method on elements and include the border width and padding width. (It was a true doozy to figure out why I had to do that.) I reviewed how jQuery determines if the element is a `Window` and handled it similarly. Ultimately, this is what I ended up doing in my use case:

```
function getWidth(e) {
    if (e != null && e === e.window) {
        return $(e).width();
    }
    const css = window.getComputedStyle(e[0]);
    const width = parseInt(css.width);
    const pLeft = parseInt(css.paddingLeft);
    const pRight = parseInt(css.paddingRight);
    const bLeft = parseInt(css.borderLeft);
    const bRight = parseInt(css.borderRight);
    return width + pLeft + pRight + bLeft + bRight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### i found the answer!!!

this is not correct sintax:

const getprop = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue("margin-top");

---

this is the correct:

you just need to write an whole 'document.querySelector(el)'

const getprop =
window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('.burger__menu')).getPropertyValue("margin-top");

---

it will be work 100%

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on my Angular6 project. none of those solutions seemed to work out for me. turned out that the problem was due to an element which was specified as `dropdown` but it didn't have dropdown options in it. take a look at code below:

```
<span class="nav-link" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="material-icons "
                           style="font-size: 2rem">notifications</i>
                        <span class="notification"></span>
                        <p>
                            <span class="d-lg-none d-md-block">Some Actions</span>
                        </p>
                    </span>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-left"
                         *ngIf="global.localStorageItem('isInSadHich')"
                         aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">You have 5 new tasks</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">You're now friend with Andrew</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another Notification</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another One</a>
                    </div>
```

removing the code `data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"` solved the problem.

I myself think that by each click on the first span element, the scope expected to set style for dropdown children which did not existed in the parent span, so it threw error.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const el = document.getElementsByClassName('content-right')[0]
if (!el) return
const i = window.getComputedStyle(el).width
```

it is a way fix the error,but I can't figure it out why cant find the element,it should not be null!

Comment: Hiding the errors is not fixing the problem. Read other answers for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this error when using an input field with input type of 'number'.

Make sure your field is focused before the input changes. You can do this with a javascript function for focusing fields with ids.

Eg:

```
const inputField = document.getElementById('myInputField');

inputField.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
  this.focus();
});
```

Answer (score -41):

The error message is pretty straightforward: [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) expects an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) as its first argument, and something else was passed to it.

If what you are really asking for is help with debugging your skin, you should make more of an effort to isolate the error.

Comment: You mean, it expects an ìnstance of the object `Element`?

Comment: Does not sound like a constructive criticism.

Comment: I agree with your point but it should be a comment not an answer.