# I'm getting any arror in Ionic 4 slider swiper-zoom-container

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic4, swiper.js

I have a image modal slider in ionic 4, witch i'm using as image viewer, it zoom the images but when i zoom the image and i try to swip i'm getting an error

**The slider code**

```
<ion-slides [options]="slideOpts" pager="true" #slider zoom="true">
<ion-slide *ngFor="let img of this.imgs">
  <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img-loader src="{{ path + img.img }}" useImg></img-loader>
  </div>
</ion-slide>
```

**The error i'm getting**

```
zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at Object.getTranslate (chunk-f9db771e.js:1)
at t.onTouchMove (chunk-f9db771e.js:1)
at HTMLDivElement.n (chunk-f9db771e.js:1)
at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:498)
at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
at HTMLDivElement.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1781)
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: `parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'`

Comment: but what exactly is parameter 1 in my case?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29196991